# Calculator shows an error: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator, and I'm kinda stuck at the mod and exp operations, whenever I try to use them I get  below error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

**This is  the event in which the error happens :**

```
private void Equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (operationPerf)
            {
                case "+":
                    TB.Text = (result + Double.Parse(TB.Text)).ToString();
                    CO.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "-":
                    TB.Text = (result - Double.Parse(TB.Text)).ToString();
                    CO.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "*":
                    TB.Text = (result * Double.Parse(TB.Text)).ToString();
                    CO.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "/":
                    TB.Text = (result / Double.Parse(TB.Text)).ToString();
                    CO.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "Mod":
                    TB.Text = (result % Double.Parse(TB.Text)).ToString();
                    CO.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "Exp":
                    TB.Text = Math.Exp(Double.Parse(TB.Text) * Math.Log((result) * 4)).ToString();
                    CO.Text = "";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            result = Double.Parse(TB.Text); // Here is where the error happens
            CO.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: What does the debugger show `TB.Text` contains before an exception is thrown?

Comment: It contains this "23Exp3"

Comment: If I asked you to convert this to a number, can you do it: *23Exp3*? Well if you cannot then the computer cannot do it either so you will get an error.

Comment: Good point, how could I go around it? Storing the operation in a different var and then pushing it to TB.Text, and give it's value to result ends up not doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `operationPerf` is none of the expected operators, so the default case is executed and the textbox still contains the original expression (e.g. `"23Exp3"`), which, of course, cannot be converted to a `double`.

You should really separate the calculator logic from input and output. Create a `Calculator` class in a separate code file (Calculator.cs)

```
public class Calculator
{
    public double Result { get; set; }

    public void Calculate(string operation, double operand)
    {
        switch (operation)
        {
            case "+":
                Result = Result + operand;
                break;
            case "-":
                Result = Result - operand;
                break;
            case "*":
                Result = Result * operand;
                break;
            case "/":
                Result = Result / operand;
                break;
            case "Mod":
                Result = Result % operand;
                break;
            case "Exp":
                Result = Math.Exp(operand * Math.Log(Result * 4));

                // Did you want this instead?
                // Result = Math.Pow(Result, operand);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It is easier to understand, as it does only contain pure math and does not require any parsing or formatting.

In a form field (at the top of the form class) you can then declare

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Calculator _calculator = new Calculator();

    ...
}
```

The event handler is the easier too

```
private void Equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Double.TryParse(TB.Text, out double operand)) {
        _calculator.Calculate(operationPerf, operand);
        TB.Text = _calculator.Result.ToString();
        CO.Text = "";
    } else {
        MsgBox.Show("The TextBox does not contain a number");
    }
}
```

If the textbox still contains `"23Exp3"`, you will not be able to convert it to a `double`. Either use different textboxes to enter the operation, the operator (a number) and the result, or separate the string into its three parts (the 2 numbers and the operation).

I really don't understand the logic behind `Math.Exp(operand * Math.Log(Result * 4))`. Since I do not know the expected behavior, I cannot give you any advice. Did you want to use `Math.Pow` instead?

```
public static double Pow(double x,  double y)
```

> Returns a specified number raised to the specified power.

See: [Math.Pow Method (Double, Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I'm confused as to where I should create the Calculator class, I have it above the form one, but it doesn't really work, neither it works within the form class, but this time around it says that " 'Form1.Calculator.result' is never assigned to"

Comment: Create a new code file for the `Calculator` class. In Visual Studio right-click the project > Add > Class... I.E. the class code is in another file, but the declaration of the `_calculator` object is in the form, I changed the example code.

Comment: Tried that, still getting " Field 'Calculator.result' is never assigned to " warning, which in return makes none of the operations to work. Should mention that I get that after I do initialize result with double, at the beginning.

Comment: In my example code `Result` is a property, not a field and it is automatically initialized to `0.0` when the calcuator object is created. You must still have a result field somewhere. There should not be any `result` field (written in all lower case). Check your code against my example code (I made edits since the first post).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the user to enter something like this: *10Exp3*. And you expect your program to raise 10 to the power of 3 and then show the result. So you expect 1000 in this case. But you are simply doing this:

```
case "Exp":
    TB.Text = Math.Exp(Double.Parse(TB.Text) * Math.Log((result) * 4)).ToString();
```

First issue with your code is, you are using `Exp` because this is the documentation for `Exp`:

> Returns e raised to the specified power.

Do you want *e* raised to the specified power? No you do not. So you cannot use that method. But even if you could and wanted to (and maybe you do want *e*), the computer cannot convert *10Exp3* to a number--you have to tell it what to do.

Here is how (Read my comments inline for more clarity):

```
var input = "10Exp3";
// Let's split the numbers using <Exp>
var splits = input.Split(new[] { "Exp" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// Let's try and convert the first part into a double and see if it works
double numberBase = 0;
if (!double.TryParse(splits[0], out numberBase))
{
    // The part before the word Exp is
    // not a number, perhaps show an error to the user in a message box
}

// Now let's try and convert the second part 
double exponent = 0;
if (!double.TryParse(splits[1], out exponent))
{
    // The part after the word Exp is
    // not a number, perhaps show an error to the user in a message box
}

// Now we will call the Pow method or use Math.Exp if you want e
double result = Math.Pow(numberBase, exponent);
```